# Problem with lit-html, doesn't recognize @click and other attributes from the library

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webstorm, lit-html

My problem is that WebStorm doesn't work as I expected with lit-html.

I installed with `$npm install lit html`. I have node modules directory, I have my package JSON and lock JSON with everything standard inside for new library, yet don't find any of the elements. For example don't recognize `@click` as an event listener:

```
 import {html, render} from 'lit-html';
 let example = (data) =>  html `
  <div class="contact card">
    <div>
        <a class="far fa-user-circle gravatar"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <h2>Name: John</h2>
        <button @click=${data} class="details">Details</button>
        <div class="details" id="1">
            <p>Phone number: 0847759632</p>
            <p>Email: john@john.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`;
```

Answer (score 3):

*lit-html* is not yet supported, please vote for [WEB-32640](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32640) to be notified on any progress with this feature